# @Valid does not work when @RequestPart is used in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

`@Valid` annotation is not calling validator when `@RequestPart` is used. In other places I used `@Valid` with `@RequestBody` and it works fine.
There is no error just passing the wrong validation also.

Below is the code.

```
@InitBinder("campaignCreatorDTO")
public void initCreatorDTOBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    binder.addValidators(new CreatorDTOValidator());
}

@PostMapping(value = "/creator", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @Valid
ResponseDTO creator(@Valid @RequestPart("json") CampaignCreatorDTO campaignCreatorDTO,
                    @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile adGraphic) {
}
```

Comment: You are overriding the validator and bind it to a model attribute. Remove the `"campaignCreatorDTO"` from the `@InitBinder` and try again. If that fails(because you then set the global validator) try using the argument name `json` instead of the model argument name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427494/why-didnt-initbinder-call-on-submit-form), `@InitBinder` uses the value passed to it for targeted validation with same named request parameters or model attributes. The problem is that you have neither since you utilize a multipart form data input in your particular endpoint `/creator`. Therefore removing the naming restriction from the `@InitBinder` would be the solution.

```
@InitBinder
public void initCreatorDTOBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run validation in the controller method using Validator Bean:

> org.springframework.validation.Validator

```
@Autowired
protected Validator validator;

PostMapping(value = "/creator", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @Valid
ResponseDTO creator(@RequestPart("json") CampaignCreatorDTO campaignCreatorDTO,
                    @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile adGraphic) {
    validator.validate(campaignCreatorDTO);
}
```

Comment: still not calling validator. same issue persists.

Comment: I had already tried above code and it does not call validator.

Comment: Please have a look into below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json
and also provide more detail  creatorDTO and CampaignCreatorDTO.

Comment: @Anjali have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175009/valid-annotation-is-not-working-in-spring-boot use this import org.springframework.validation.Validator